# How to keep code synchronous when there are asynchronous calls inside of loops

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous

I'm filling an array inside a loop and I need the full array when the loop finishes.

I've tried handling everything through promises or by using a counter but i can't seem to figure out the trick here.

```
lambda.listFunctions({}).promise()
    .then((data) => {
        data.Functions.forEach(func => {
            lambda.listTags({ Resource: func.FunctionArn }).promise()
                .then((data) => {
                    if ("Edge" in data.Tags) {
                        available_functions.push(func.FunctionName)
                    }
                })
        });
          console.log(available_functions)
    })
```

available_functions is always empty unless I console log it at the end of each foreach loop and then I have it returning 18 times which is not what I want.

Comment: Can you use the `await` keyword?

Comment: I've tried it by making the anonymous function In the foreach asynchronous and using await but it doesn't slow this bad boy down, or at least I haven't been using it right

Comment: @Dai See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: "I need the full array when the loop finishes"  actually can't be done. You can construct an array of promises to supply data and use `Promise` all to proceed when all data has arrived, or remove the `forEach` loop and write an asynchronous loop and `await` individual proimises of data. In either case it is not possible to process data obtained synchronously with making requests for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just promise it chain it to ensure all operations within the scope of the `then` completes before going down the chain.

```
lambda.listFunctions({}).promise()
  .then(data => {
    const { Functions } = data;

    // I converted this from forEach to for of
    for (const func of Functions) {
      lambda.listTags({ Resource: func.FunctionArn }).promise()
        .then(data => {
          if ("Edge" in data.Tags) {
            available_functions.push(func.FunctionName)
          }
        })
    }
  // also you can promise chain it if available_functions is within scope
  })
  .then(() => console.log(available_functions))
```

Or the cleaner `async` `await` way would look something like...

```
async fn() {
  const available_functions = [];

  const { Functions } = await lambda.listFunctions({}).promise();

  for (const func of Functions) {
    const tags = await lambda.listTags({ Resource: func.FunctionArn }).promise();

    if ("Edge" in tags) {
      available_functions.push(func.FunctionName)
    }

  }

  return available_functions

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You may have misread the linked article -  `for.. of` loops are synchronous.

Comment: @traktor53 ah good call. Yeah definitely a misread. I updated my comment, hopefully the code still works

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.all` with your problem. See documentation on [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

```
const available_functions = [];

lambda.listFunctions({}).promise()
    .then((data) => {
        const promises = []; // Collect promises

        data.Functions.forEach(func => {
            promises.push(lambda.listTags({ Resource: func.FunctionArn }).promise()
                .then((data) => {
                    available_functions.push(func.FunctionName)
                    return Promise.resolve(available_functions);
                })
            );
        });

        Promise.all(promises)
            .then(results => {
                    console.log(available_functions)
                // or
                    console.log(results[results.length - 1]);
            });
    });
```